# The this keyword not working with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I'm learning ES6, I just want to convert my ES5 knowledge to ES6.

here's my ES5 code:

```
function click() {
  this.className += ' grab';
  setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'remove'), 0);
};
```

and here's my ES6 code:

```
const click = () => {
  this.className += ' grab';
  setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'remove'), 0);
  console.log('RENDERING');
}
```

My problem is **this.className += ' grab';** and **setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'remove'), 0);** didn't run the function. But **console.log** shows on the log.

> Is **this** method don't work on arrow functions?

Comment: `this` is not a method, and is different inside an arrow function - read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to understand the difference ... `didn't run the function` yes, it did, you just don't know what you're doing yet

Comment: `this` keyword functions differently in arrow functions. [Read this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) of the documentation.

Comment: Aside - Consider using `el.classList.add('grab')` (and `el.classList.remove('grab')`) instead of manipulating the string of class names manually.  [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: This shows that not all functions should be converted to arrow functions just because arrow functions are cool :p arrow functions serve a specific purpose and should only be used as appropriate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's not really enough context to give you a good answer, but one thing stands out. Arrow functions maintain scope, so `this` inside `function click()` and `const click` may well be different. In the ES6 version, `this` will refer to whatever was `this` during the closure creation, which may not be what you want.

[Arrow Functions at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) clears it up:

> An arrow function does not have its own `this.`

…Which means that `this` will be inherited from the declaring scope.

ES6 arrow functions aren't just a new way of declaring functions, and there's nothing inherently wrong with `function myFunction(...)` syntax, nor is it going away. Arrow functions avoid some verbosity when passing a function as an argument (e.g. to `forEach`) and avoid the need to rebind a function to a different `this` in some cases. Converting all function declarations to arrow syntax is not an upgrade.

Comment: @jaromanda-x Yeah, you're probably right, especially if you assume that the function is normally called as an object method, which is why it would even have a className property. Shrug.

Answer (score 3):

In Arrow Functions, `this` isn't the `this` you would expect. `this` in Arrow Functions is defined when you create the function - not when it is called.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) for more information on that.

Thanks to @Jaromanda X from the comments - In this case, **keep using standard function notation** (`function() {...}`) - i.e. just because you bought a new screwdriver, doesn't mean the old hammer isn't still the best tool for banging in nails

Comment: `this` does exist, otherwise the OP would get errors - `this` is from the bounding lexical scope

Comment: @JaromandaX you're right. let me fix that

Comment: `keep using standard function notation` - i.e. just because you bought a new screwdriver, doesn't mean the old hammer isn't still the best tool for banging in nails

Comment: @JaromandaX that's actually a very good analogy. Do you mind if I put that in my answer?

Comment: Feel free - it's one of my better ones :p

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you just need to slightly restructure things.

```
setTimeout(() => {this.className = 'remove'}, 0)
```

You have parenthesis vs curly braces.

your `this` may or may not work depending on how things are structured in the other code

Comment: absolutely no difference in this context - in other context, the difference is what the arrow function returns

Answer (score 0):

```
       const click = () => {
           console.log(this);
           this.className += ' grab';
          setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'remove'), 0);
          console.log('RENDERING');
      }
      click();
```

'this' in the arrow function represents from wherever it is called. for eg if i open the browser and goto console and type above code then 'this' will become window object since the function is called from global enviroment. Also arrow function doesnot have its own 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `this` for arrow function to access functions and data. Your code should be something like

```
const click = () => {
  this.className += ' grab';
  setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'remove'), 0);
  console.log('RENDERING');
}.bind(this)
```

It will bind `this` for arrow function and you can access those variable and functions.

Comment: it will bind `this` only if it's defined in the object though

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords. Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods, and **they cannot be used as constructors.**